# 401 Unauthorized error when trying to access schema

Tags: sharepoint, schema

I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to import a schema.

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" schemaLocation="http://yak/NSI_FCS_Bin/niem-constrained/structures/2.0/structures.xsd"/>
```

I have uploaded the schema and the correct folder structure using a module. However, when the parent schema tries to import this schema (and all others) I get a 401 Unauthorized error. But if I type the exact same url into a web browser, I can view/download the file just fine. I made sure that I was logged into my sharepoint site before executing the code. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain where in SharePoint you import the schema and how?

Comment: Yes that line is from the parent schema which I have loaded into the project by using an embedded resource. I would make the other schemas embedded resources as well but I do not know how to link the schemaLocation attribute to a Properties.Resources.schema file

Comment: ok i think we are off topic here since this site is for SharePoint specific questions. Chances are your question will be received better on Stackexchange since it is more general VS2010 question. Hence i have closed the question.

Comment: You need to give more detail about how the schema is used. What do you use it for? Exactly where do you get the 401 error?

Comment: I was getting the 401 error when I would hover over the blue squiggly line inside Visual Studio. I would also get the error when I tried to validate an XML document that called on the schema. I have since gotten around the problem by copying all the schemas to the SharePoint Layouts folder so I can call on them using a local path rather then an website URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One work around for this problem is to add the schemas to your Template\Layouts folder and call the schema from there. I am still unsure why I was getting the unauthorized errors, but I did not get those errors when calling the schemas from the Template\Layouts folder. Hope this helps!